# Ansible: shell script output always empty

Tags: shell, ansible

I'm trying to insert an output of Linux shell to a variable, but for some reason, the variable always empty.

Here is the Ansible code:

```
  - name: Check PHP version
    shell: php -v 2> /dev/null | awk '{print $2; exit}'
    register: php_version

  - debug: var=php_version
```

And here is the output:

```
ok: [10.0.0.5] => {
    "php_version": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": "php -v 2> /dev/null | awk '{print $2; exit}'", 
        "delta": "0:00:00.015180", 
        "end": "2017-01-08 18:41:00.323773", 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2017-01-08 18:41:00.308593", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stdout": "", 
        "stdout_lines": [], 
        "warnings": []
    }
}
```

When i run the command directly on the server, i get a valid result:

```
php -v 2> /dev/null | awk '{print $2; exit}'
7.0.14
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. I copied your plays and ran on both ansible 2.0.1.0 on macos and ansible 2.3.0 on ubuntu and I get stdout correctly on both.

Comment: I cannot reproduce either. When you run the command directly on the server, are you using the same user and shell `/bin/sh` that Ansible uses?

Comment: No. Ansible runs with a different user from a designated server.

Comment: Try running it without the `2> /dev/null | awk '{print $2; exit}'`, hopefully you should see the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to possible reasons, why you can run the command from CLI, but not Ansible, most likely the path to the `php` executable is not defined in the `PATH` variable when you run shell through a non-interactive SSH session<sup>*</sup> (as Ansible does).

Use a full path instead of just `php` in the `shell` module argument.

---

> What could be the issue?

As you are using a pipeline in the shell call, the return code will be that of the last command (`awk`) and although the first one fails, you won't be notified.

Awk does not get any input to process and it quits gracefully, and because you are redirecting stderr to `/dev/null` you don't see any error from the `php` command.

For example if you explicitly run a non-existent command:

```
- name: Check PHP version
    shell: qwerty -v 2> /dev/null | awk '{print $2; exit}'
    register: php_version

- debug: var=php_version
```

you will also get:

```
"rc": 0,
"start": "2017-01-09 06:35:10.588258",
"stderr": "",
"stdout": "",
"stdout_lines": [],
"warnings": []
```

---

<sup>*</sup> See the [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell) question on Unix.SE.