# Ansible output of registered variable showing null

Tags: ansible

I am trying to get the output of a shell command showing the public ip of a `kubernetes` service in `ansible` as follows:

```
   - name: Get jenkins url
      shell: "kubectl get svc nginx-ingress-controller -o json | jq '.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip'"
      register: public_ip


    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ public_ip.stdout_lines }}"
```

This displays a `null` value:

```
TASK [Debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "null"
    ]
}
```

However when I run the command manually, I do get the public IP

```
▶ kubectl get svc nginx-ingress-controller -o json | jq '.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip'
"11.111.123.11"
```

Why is that?

Have also tried this with `public_ip.stdout` instead of `public_ip.stdout_lines` with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

What I can recommend is to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535189/ansible-shell-script-output-always-empty) answer as I think it should fix the issue for you.